# sql to select orders with lowest count

Tags: sql

```
+-----------+-----------+
|id.        |count.     |
+-----------+-----------+
|     192044|          1|
|     192045|          1|
|     192046|          1|
|     793820|          2|
|     285030|          2|
|     924949|          5|
+-----------+-----------+
```

How would I write my SQL statement to select the customers who have the min count?
Is this a ranking function?

SUDO of what I think it should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, count(id) as count from base_table group by id)
GROUP BY id, count
HAVING order_count = (SELECT MIN(count) FROM (SELECT id, count(id) as count from base_table id))
```

Comment: Are you familiar with aggregation and the HAVING clause?

Comment: @shree.pat18 yes, but unsure how to construct a subquery for the having statement

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Please see my sudo, to see if I am correct @D-Shih

Comment: @dataviews I think the `order by` makes no sense in a subquery, btw could you show us what's your DBMS? because that might help us answer your query

Comment: pyspark I am using

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with base as(
  select 
     id
     , count
     , min(count) over() as min_value
  from table
  order by count desc
 ) select *
   from base
   where count = min_value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM <DataBase_Table_name>
ORDER BY count ASC;
```

Comment: Please add context around code-only answers

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Select id
From tbl t
Outer apply (select min(count) as mincount from tbl) s
Where count = mincount
```

Basically you use a subquery to get global minimum count, and then use OUTER APPLY to combine each row from your table with this result set.